# Query End Issue

Tags: mysql

I take a screen shot when too many connection occurs on my website and there are two types of queries

A)  2 | query end                                                             | REPLACE INTO TABLE1  (COL1,COL2,DATE) VALUES 
* table is innodb and i dont know why its taking time(2 sec) and whats query end ?

B)  1 | Waiting for table level lock                                           SELECT COL FROM TABLE2 WHERE COL1=1 AND COL2 IN ()
* Table is myisam and i guess this can be solved by converting myisam to innodb.

Can anyone suggest how to solve A)

Comment: do you control your application that query the database? both queries seems have no sense and/or broken.

Comment: @Alex these are obvious queries so i write incomplte